# Q/Promise handle callback params

Tags: node.js, promise, q

```
  var Q = require("q");
  function test(v){
    var deferred = Q.defer()
    if (v) {
      console.log("success");
      deferred.resolve();
    }
    else{
      console.log("failed");
      deferred.reject(new Error("failed"))
    } 
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  var over = function(url){
    console.log("hahaha")
    console.log(url)
  }

  var failed = function(){
    console.log("wuwuw")
  }

  test().then(over, failed)

  test().then(over("localhost"), failed)
```

When `test().then(over, failed)`, function over should not execute,The program can do well,
I can get the result:

```
  failed
  wuwuw
```

But when I add params for function over, the function over will execute. I will get:

```
  failed
  hahaha
  localhost
  wuwuw
```

Obviously, I don't want the function over execute, but I need it get the params when test() resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I add params for function over, the function over will execute.

That's because you're calling it. You still need to pass a function to `then`:

```
test().then(function(testResult) {
    over("localhost");
}, failed)
```